# Obtaining data from PubMed using python

Tags: python, text-mining

I have a list of PubMed entries along with the PubMed ID's. I would like to create a python script or use python which accepts a PubMed id number as an input and then fetches the abstract from the PubMed website.

So far I have come across NCBI Eutilities and the importurl library in Python but I don't know how I should go about writing a template.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow, I was working on a similar project myself just a week or so ago!

**Edit:** I recently updated the code to take advantage of [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  I have my own virtualenv for it, but you can install it with pip.

Basically, my program takes a pubmed ID, a DOI, or a text file of lines of pubmed IDs and/or DOIs, and grabs information about the article.  It can easily be tweaked for your own needs to obtain the abstract, but here's my code:

```
import re
import sys
import traceback
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

class PubMedObject(object):
    soup = None
    url = None

    # pmid is a PubMed ID
    # url is the url of the PubMed web page
    # search_term is the string used in the search box on the PubMed website
    def __init__(self, pmid=None, url='', search_term=''):
        if pmid:
            pmid = pmid.strip()
            url = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/%s" % pmid
        if search_term:
            url = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%s" % search_term
        page = requests.get(url).text
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

        # set the url to be the fixed one with the PubMedID instead of the search_term
        if search_term:
            try:
                url = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/%s" % self.soup.find("dl",class_="rprtid").find("dd").text
            except AttributeError as e:  # NoneType has no find method
                print("Error on search_term=%s" % search_term)
        self.url = url

    def get_title(self):
        return self.soup.find(class_="abstract").find("h1").text

    #auths is the string that has the list of authors to return
    def get_authors(self):
        result = []
        author_list = [a.text for a in self.soup.find(class_="auths").findAll("a")]
        for author in author_list:
            lname, remainder = author.rsplit(' ', 1)
            #add periods after each letter in the first name
            fname = ".".join(remainder) + "."
            result.append(lname + ', ' + fname)

        return ', '.join(result)

    def get_citation(self):
        return self.soup.find(class_="cit").text

    def get_external_url(self):
        url = None
        doi_string = self.soup.find(text=re.compile("doi:"))
        if doi_string:
            doi = doi_string.split("doi:")[-1].strip().split(" ")[0][:-1]
            if doi:
                url = "http://dx.doi.org/%s" % doi
        else:
            doi_string = self.soup.find(class_="portlet")
            if doi_string:
                doi_string = doi_string.find("a")['href']
                if doi_string:
                    return doi_string

        return url or self.url

    def render(self):
        template_text = ''
        with open('template.html','r') as template_file:
            template_text = template_file.read()

        try:
            template_text = template_text.replace("{{ external_url }}", self.get_external_url())
            template_text = template_text.replace("{{ citation }}", self.get_citation())
            template_text = template_text.replace("{{ title }}", self.get_title())
            template_text = template_text.replace("{{ authors }}", self.get_authors())
            template_text = template_text.replace("{{ error }}", '')
        except AttributeError as e:
            template_text = template_text.replace("{{ external_url }}", '')
            template_text = template_text.replace("{{ citation }}", '')
            template_text = template_text.replace("{{ title }}", '')
            template_text = template_text.replace("{{ authors }}", '')
            template_text = template_text.replace("{{ error }}", '<!-- Error -->')

        return template_text.encode('utf8')

def start_table(f):
    f.write('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="resourcesTable">\n');
    f.write('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n');

def end_table(f):
    f.write('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</table>\n');
    f.write('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n');

def start_accordion(f):
    f.write('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="accordion">\n');

def end_accordion(f):
    f.write('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n');

def main(args):
    try:
        # program's main code here
        print("Parsing pmids.txt...")
        with open('result.html', 'w') as sum_file:
            sum_file.write('<!--\n')
        with open('pmids.txt','r') as pmid_file:
        with open('result.html','a') as sum_file:
        for pmid in pmid_file:
            sum_file.write(pmid)
        sum_file.write('\n-->\n')
        with open('pmids.txt','r') as pmid_file:
            h3 = False
            h4 = False
            table_mode = False
            accordion_mode = False
            with open('result.html', 'a') as sum_file:
                for pmid in pmid_file:
                    if pmid[:4] == "####":
                        if h3 and not accordion_mode:
                            start_accordion(sum_file)
                            accordion_mode = True
                        sum_file.write('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<h4><a href="#">%s</a></h4>\n' % pmid[4:].strip())
                        h4 = True
                    elif pmid[:3] == "###":
                        if h4:
                            if table_mode:
                                end_table(sum_file)
                                table_mode = False
                            end_accordion(sum_file)
                            h4 = False
                            accordion_mode = False
                        elif h3:
                            end_table(sum_file)
                            table_mode = False
                        sum_file.write('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<h3><a href="#">%s</a></h3>\n' % pmid[3:].strip())
                        h3 = True                        
                    elif pmid.strip():
                        if (h3 or h4) and not table_mode:
                            start_table(sum_file)
                            table_mode = True
                        if pmid[:4] == "http":
                            if pmid[:18] == "http://dx.doi.org/":
                                sum_file.write(PubMedObject(search_term=pmid[18:]).render())
                            else:
                                print("url=%s" % pmid)
                                p = PubMedObject(url=pmid).render()
                                sum_file.write(p)
                                print(p)
                        elif pmid.isdigit():
                            sum_file.write(PubMedObject(pmid).render())
                        else:
                            sum_file.write(PubMedObject(search_term=pmid).render())
                if h3:
                    if h4:
                        end_table(sum_file)
                        end_accordion(sum_file)
                    else:
                        end_table(sum_file)
            pmid_file.close()
        print("Done!")

    except BaseException as e:
        print traceback.format_exc()
        print "Error: %s %s" % (sys.exc_info()[0], e.args)
        return 1
    except:
        # error handling code here
        print "Error: %s" % sys.exc_info()[0]
        return 1  # exit on error
    else:
        raw_input("Press enter to exit.")
        return 0  # exit errorlessly

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

It now returns a HTML file based on the information it downloaded.  Here is the template.txt:

```
<tr>{{ error }}
    <td valign="top" class="resourcesICO"><a href="{{ external_url }}" target="_blank"><img src="/image/ico_sitelink.gif" width="24" height="24" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="{{ external_url }}">{{ title }}</a><br />
    {{ authors }}<br />
    <em>{{ citation }}</em></td>
</tr>
```

When you run it, the program will ask you for the DOI or the Pubmed ID.  If you do not provide one, it will read pmids.txt.Feel free to use the code as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you Bobort, I am going to tweak this code so that it just gets the abstract info. Also, I'll be integrating this with another script which maps the pubmed id to the structural title and the citation title.

Comment: Why did I get a down vote?  How unhelpful to just down vote an answer and leave!

Comment: Hi Bobort, I think someone else has down voted the answer. I will fix this for you.

Comment: Isn't there a short way to get the abstract using Biopython's Entrez tool?

Comment: To answer myself, there is, and I provide an example in another answer.

Comment: I gave a down vote because this is a screen scraping approach rather than retrieving data through the json or xml api. Is there some good reason for this approach?

Comment: I am not aware of retrieving data through a json or xml api at the requested website.  The original question did not make any specifications as such.  My answer is simply one possible way to do it, and the one that was accepted.  I would like to know how this so-called "screen scraping" approach is not allowed by community standards.

Comment: any comments on the full text ?

Comment: This is the wrong approach, scraping is silly when you are given an API, is limited and abusive.  Use Eutils! https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25501/

Answer (score 37):

Using [Biopython](http://biopython.org)'s module called [Entrez](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Entrez-module.html), you can get the abstract along with all other metadata quite easily. This will print the abstract:

```
from Bio.Entrez import efetch

def print_abstract(pmid):
    handle = efetch(db='pubmed', id=pmid, retmode='text', rettype='abstract')
    print handle.read()
```

And here is a function that will fetch XML and return just the abstract:

```
from Bio.Entrez import efetch, read

def fetch_abstract(pmid):
    handle = efetch(db='pubmed', id=pmid, retmode='xml')
    xml_data = read(handle)[0]
    try:
        article = xml_data['MedlineCitation']['Article']
        abstract = article['Abstract']['AbstractText'][0]
        return abstract
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

P.S. I actually had the need to do this kind of stuff in a real task, so I organized the code into a class -- [see this gist](https://gist.github.com/langner/7820246).

Comment: That looks like a very nice module.  I had no idea it existed.  However, one good thing about my code is that it obtains DOI values so that the URL retrieved is as general as possible.  I'm assuming that such features might exist in the Entrez module, but I haven't looked in depth at it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by URL... biopython does all the querying behind the scenes, so you don't need to play with any URLs.

Comment: It's okay.  My application produces the 'http://dx.doi.org/' so that I can use it in a website.  Instead of going to the PubMed stuff, I want to go directly to the article.  The most general way I know of right now that is programmer friendly is to use the DOI schema.

Comment: Oh I see, but that is orthogonal to this question. If you have the DOI, you can always build the string "http://dx.doi.org/"+doi and use it. The question was how to get data from Pubmed.

Comment: Indeed, Karol.  However, I needed to get specific details about an article, and PubMed offers a consistent format that I can utilize to obtain that information.  Otherwise, I would have to figure out where that specific information is located on each unique doi page, which is usually different from the next.

Comment: FYI: the corresponding pip package is called `biopython`

Comment: Is it possible to query the whole paper text (and not only the abstract)?

Answer (score 3):

The [metapub](https://pypi.org/project/metapub/) library was built for this.  Metapub been tested on more than 1/3rd of the PubMed database (as of 2019).

```
from metapub import PubMedFetcher

pmids = [<your list of ids>]
for pmid in pmids:
    article = fetch.article_by_id(pmid)
    print(article.abstract)
```

And if you want to get to the full text of each article, you can do this:

```
from metapub import FindIt

pmids = [<yourlist>]
for pmid in pmids:
    src = FindIt(pmid)
    print(src.doi)
    print(src.url)
```

I have tested this library against literally millions of articles, to the point where the Medline XML (i.e. Entrez) parser is about 99% robust.  And trust me, this data is messy.

Source: I'm the author.

Answer (score 1):

Pubmed articles have the form: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?Id

If you know the id then you can fetch the above and you will have access to the article.
The abstract is contained within a structure like :

```
<div class="abstr"><h3>Abstract</h3><div class=""><p>α-latrotoxin and snake presynaptic phospholipases A2 neurotoxins target the presynaptic membrane of axon terminals of the neuromuscular junction....</p></div></div>
```

You would then need a tool to extract that. I would suggest using : http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

You will still need a tool to actually fetch the html. For that I would use phantom.js or the ever popular requests module.

Your workflow would like something like :

```
pubmed_ids [1,2,3]
abstracts = []

for id in pubmed_ids: 
 html_for_id = requests.get('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/{0}'.format(id))
 soup =  BeautifulSoup(html_for_id)
 abstract = soup.find('selector for abstract')
 abstracts.append(abstract)
```

Comment: any comments on the full text ?

Comment: Can we extract the full text using this approach and the DOI?

Answer (score 0):

Seems 'pattern' module can do this easily:

```html
from pattern import web
import requests

id = 27523945
url = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/{0}".format(id)
page = requests.get(url).text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
dom = web.Element(page)
print(dom.by_tag("abstracttext")[0].content)
```